"linux" and "initrd.gz" files for installation from TFTP server
Where do I get the "linux" and "initrd.gz" files, so that I can install Ubuntu 22.04 from my tftp server ?
Previously, for 20.04, i could use:
wget http://debian.ethz.ch/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/{initrd.gz,linux}

but these files don't exist for 22.04
I tried following the instructions here, downloaded the live-server-amd64.iso, extracted vmlinuz and initrd, but these files do not work. The installation starts, but then gets stuck at the beginning. So apparently, these files are not meant to be booted from tftp


The files from the iso are correct.  What boot arguments are you using?  I would guess you did not include the required url=http://...iso argument with the path to the full iso.
